# Why does my apache2 server temporarily crash when I submit forms on my django website?

Tags: django, apache, web, apache2

I have made a website using Django. It has login functionality and allows you two create, update and like posts. It works correctly on the development server running locally but when I set it up on apache2 almost all the functionality works. The parts that break are that whenever I create, update or like a post the page does not load and the apache server shuts down for a while. When I check the apache logs it gives an empty 408 error. I have tried making both the timeouts in the apache config larger and this has not helped.

I'm sorry if the answer to this is on here as I couldn't find it despite searching if you know of one please link me. If any extra info is required please ask. Thank you!

**Edit 1:**
setup

/etc/apache2/sites-available/resume_site.conf

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.andyflynnsmiles.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.andyflynnsmiles.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.andyflynnsmiles.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/resume_site-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

        ServerName www.andyflynnsmiles.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        Alias /static /home/andysmiles/resume_site/platformer_project/static
        <Directory /home/andysmiles/resume_site/platformer_project/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/andysmiles/resume_site/media
        <Directory /home/andysmiles/resume_site/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/andysmiles/resume_site/platformer_project>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/andysmiles/resume_site>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/andysmiles/resume_site/resume_site/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess resume_site python-path=/home/andysmiles/resume_site python-home=/home/andysmiles/resume_site/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup resume_site



Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias andyflynnsmiles.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/andyflynnsmiles.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/andyflynnsmiles.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer on how things are running here. How, for example are you running the django project? How is apache set up for routing? Please show some of your setup.

Comment: I have added the setup for apache routing i think but I don't know what you mean by "How, for example are you running the django project?".

Comment: And how is the django site being run?

Comment: I don't know what you mean sorry.

Comment: Well, you have to actually run it somehow. For testing it's usuallly `python manage.py runserver`, for production you might use something like gunicorn.

Comment: Oh, I am running it on a linode server running ubuntu 18.04 LTS through apache2.

Comment: So what command are you using to start the django wsgi server? I strongly suspect this is your issue ... See the docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/

Comment: I use "sudo service apache2 start" to start it running and then "sudo service apache2 restart" for updates.

Comment: Yes, see that's starting Apache, but not your django project, so Apache will have nothing to serve. You need them both running. Please read the docs link I posted, and maybe click the link about deploying with gunicorn.

Comment: No the website is up and running at andyflynnsmiles.com the only issue is it breaks when using the features stated in my question

Comment: OK, then I can't help you I don't think. You don't seem to know quite how your project is actually running, which to me points at issues there. I'm no Apache expert though - I usually use nginx, so maybe somebody with more Apache knowledge can spot an obvious issue.